# Why does Polymer use hidden and by-polymer-bundler attributes in div tag ?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

**Why does Polymer use hidden and by-polymer-bundler attributes in div tag ?**

I'm a newbie to both Javascript and Polymer JS , I'm struck with the hidden and by-polymer-bundler attributes in div tag , when i came across the same .

Had a look into [this](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-bundler/issues/556) but couldn't get to the point . Share your knowledge of the same and help me get started with Polymer 2.0

Comment: you probably want to show some code that produces your result... by default the bundler should not touch your divs

Comment: Hi dakmor , Which Comprehensive course or tutorials will help me Get started and work with Polymer 2.x ?

Comment: I would recommend this codelabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/whose-flag/index.html#0

also offical polymer 2 getting started https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/

Comment: Thanks a lot @daKmoR

Comment: an upvote of my comment would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Plus one for your comment